# Is there a word that describes an intelligent, self-aware, sentient lifeform?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

... like "human" but also applicable to other beings that are generally as intelligent (i.e. capable of complex thought, participation in a society, etc.).

Or must one describe that concept with other words? If so, is there a most-succinct or scientific way of doing so? "Intelligent lifeform"?

Comment: It has to have an ego?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The context being an attempt to describe different intelligent beings interacting with each other without referring to them as humans- as they may be some other species (fictional).

Comment: Could it be a blob of some kind?  How important is the "form" element?

Comment: Since we only know of one such species, it's kind of hard to decide what you're looking for. There is no "scientific way", because it's entirely hypothetical, and without data there is no science. "Intelligent lifeform" will work as well as anything, but it begs at least two questions: (a) what does _intelligent_ mean (outside the context of H. sapiens)? (b) what does _lifeform_ mean (outside the context of our biome on Earth)? Both have no answers.

Comment: Yes, I agree that these ideas are very subjective. I suppose the threshold I  wanted to communicate was the ability to interact with another being using a language separate from pure animalistic instinct. It's quite a gray area, but there are many words for abstract feelings that are hard or impossible to quantify, so I thought perhaps there might be one here. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: If I'm told NASA have discovered an *alien lifeform* on Europa, I wouldn't be surprised to learn it's something really basic (like plankton, say). But if they say they've discovered *alien **beings*** there, I'd naturally assume that meant ***intelligent** beings*. So my vote goes for ***being*** (of which, as John points out, we currently only know one type - ***human beings***).

Comment: What is wrong with "sentient"? Just an aside, Frank Herbert coined "ConSentiency" for the political organization that spanned multiple intelligent races.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "intelligent and self-aware – UNlike humans"? :-)

Comment: A generic way to express intelligence would be the ability to communicate your thoughts (can you please pass me the salt) and form abstract ideas (wish I could fly). Another aspect, that I think is important, is to have empathy. All living creatures are selfish by default and try to preserve themselves and their offspring (and siblings to some extent), but for a creature to be intelligent, they need to show that things beyond their own goals matter. Most of the human behavioural factors can be automated into a machine but empathy can't be.

Comment: I suspect there is in every language except English. Which makes us what? - the last to know??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with "sapient," which is widely used in science fiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it grates on me every time I hear "sentient"** being or creature in books and on screen. A "sentient creature" is one that can sense -so pretty much every creature is a sentient one.  I LIKE the word "sapient" mentioned earlier (by RoboKaren) and I'll start using that immediately to mean "a living, thinking/reasoning, aware being".

Sentience -simply means the ability to sense, process senses, to feel.

Conscious -can mean not-unconscious, in other words awake not-dormant.

Aware -can mean focused or hyper-vigilant, or that superpower we call introspection.

Sapient -showing self-awareness, wisdom, sound judgement (reason)

Comment: Your suggestions, which are useful, could form an answer but they are marred by a lack of references (and, separately, some personal opinion). On EL&U answers should be supported by some exterior authority: a dictionary definition and/or a named contextual source would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

John Norman, in one of the GOR novels, has a Gorean creature use the word "sophont" in this context (something like "I would never injure another sophont")

Answer (score 0):

"Sentient Beings" are more popular in use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! You have the seed of a good answer here, but it has been flagged for review because of how minimal it is. We prefer longer answers that have some explanation of why they are correct, and support for their assertions (for example, a dictionary citation or a corpus search). You can use the "edit" link at the lower left of your answer to add more information. Also be sure to check out the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about asking and answering. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is what "person" means.  From dictionary.com:
"5. Philosophy. a self-conscious or rational being."

The word "person" is widely used in science fiction and fantasy, too.

This question comes up a lot on various Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

**Seriophieum.**

I’m sure a search would provide a modern definition unfulfilling of what you seek if any info at all into this archaic rouser of ruminant remnants.

Comment: Would you mind terribly doing this search for us first, so that it would be easier to judge?