# What term describes something "alive" with a "brain"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, animals

What term describes something "alive" with a "brain"?

Plants are considered 'living' but without a brain, so *alive* or *life* don't work.

Fish have brains, jellyfish don't.

For my example sentence, I will be using a hypothetical viewpoint:

> > I don't just want a salad cause I am not really a vegan. I just won't eat any **[term]**, I will take jellyfish with the starfish rolls rice bowl instead, thanks. 
> > — person 1

> > Yea well, with animals, I only eat **[term]**. You can have the jellyfish all to yourself. 
> > — person 2

> > **[term]** or not, I don't eat animals. 
> > — the vegan

Please help me find the word to say "This living thing has a brain".

Thanks for any input even if it is not a one word answer I am looking for.

Comment: This thing has *a intellectual/mental capacity, power of reasoning, intellectuality etc.*

Comment: Are planets 'living things' in that sense? Many 'lower animals' don't have a brain as such, though. I thought of _encephalous_, but apparently that means 'having a head'.

Comment: The duplicate asks a different question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @jimm101 that is what I thought as well...

Comment: Answered at [Is there a word that describes an intelligent self-aware sentient lifeform?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/is-there-a-word-that-describes-an-intelligent-self-aware-sentient-lifeform/430730#430730) ('sentient'; 'sapient' ...)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that is a different question. I dont care if it is smart or self aware or anything just that it has a brain. one can have a brain and be alive but still brain dead. for example this guy: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5102206/#:~:text=Several%20years%20ago%2C%20the%20autopsy,after%20suffering%20total%20brain%20failure.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that the number of animals that have some sort of nervous system feature that resembles a brain is enormous. There are just not that many animals that don't have a brain of some sort.  There's not a sharp dividing line between having a brain and not having a brain, it's more a matter of deciding how big a bundle of ganglions has to be before you can call it a brain.

Comment: @barbecue in any case I do agree their might not be a singular term for this

Comment: Plants are **acephalous** for me. :) Call someone that and check their reaction.

Comment: @Lambie thank you sharing that term in such a funny way ... but the problem say a slab of meat ... well it is acephalous but it did have a brain ... I am not wanting to split hairs like it does not have one now... I am more so seeking something that says it had or has a brain

Comment: I highly doubt that the term you think exists would fit all three utterances. Truth be told, I don't get it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a distinct terminology to distinguish animals with a brain and animals without a brain in biology/zoology/neuroscience and also in culinary world per your context. It is not always clear if we can call the concentration of nervous tissue a brain in some smaller animals and there is sometimes no consensus also, like in the case of planarians (a type of flatworm) where the mass of nervous tissue they possess is called a *simple brain* by some experts or *cerebral ganglion* by others. Additionally, almost all animals have a brain with a few exceptions like jellyfish, starfish, sea urchins, sea cucumbers, clams, oysters, sea anemones, sea sponges, men-of-war, sea lilies, sea squirts, corals. Sponges are one of the most exceptional animals as they have no brain and no nervous system at all. The closest common distinction related to nervous system is vertebrates (animals that have a backbone/spine) vs. invertebrates (animals that don't have a backbone/spine); although it is not just about brain. Invertebrates can have a brain too. *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vertebrate)* has a detailed definition of a *vertebrate*:

> any of a subphylum (Vertebrata) of chordates that comprises animals (such as mammals, birds, reptiles, amphibians, and fishes) typically having a bony or cartilaginous spinal column which replaces the notochord, a distinct head containing a brain which arises as an enlarged part of the nerve cord, and an internal usually bony skeleton and that includes some primitive forms (such as lampreys) in which the spinal column is absent and the notochord persists throughout life

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertebrate)* has this relevant sentence in *Vertebrate* article also:

> The vertebrates are the only chordate group with neural cephalisation, the concentration of brain functions in the head.

Having said that, I was checking if there is a term starting with *encephalo-* as it is the combining form of words having to do with the brain, from ancient Greek *ἐγκέϕαλος* 'encephalos' brain. I couldn't find a relevant word in *OED* and I thought *encephalous* could work but it has a very specific usage in zoology:

> Of molluscs: Possessing a distinct head; belonging to the Encephala *n.* - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61643)*

There is also Latin *cerebro-*, combining form of *cerebrum* 'brain' but I couldn't find a relevant word with this form also. For example, *cerebrous* is not listed in dictionaries and *cerebrate* has a very different meaning.

Surprisingly, I've found two rare words in *[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/encephalata)* citing The Century Dictionary with relevant definitions; although these terms are not really used in science and they appear to be very rare words, so most people would not understand:

> **encephalata** Animals which have an encephalon, as all cranial vertebrates: nearly synonymous with *Vertebrata*, and exactly with *Craniota*.
>
> **encephalate** Having an encephalon, or a brain and skull; cranial, as a vertebrate.

Comment: men-of-war... LMAO oh my lets no go there please delete that. But this is the best answer so far thank you.

Comment: " Portuguese man o' war, also known as the man-of-war, is a marine hydrozoan found in the Atlantic Ocean and the Indian Ocean." - [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_man_o%27_war)

Comment: interesting... well I thought it was a joke. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4):

There’s plenty of references online to brainless animals  eg. from  [Science](https://www.science.org/content/article/if-alive-sleeps-brainless-creatures-shed-light-why-we-slumber)

> One of the first **brainless creatures** shown to sleep, the upside-down jellyfish, pulses its bell more slowly at night than in the day.

It’s hard to find references to the opposite. Here’s a few but they seem less “standard”.

> Largest **Brain Animal**
> Many mammals have the largest brain size compared to their body size. Some mammals have the largest brain size, as given below;
> Sperm Whale. […].
> killer whale.  […].
> Elephant.  […].
> — https://www.vedantu.com/biology/largest-brain-animal

> *Large-**Brained Animal** Models of Huntington’s Disease: Sheep.*
> The limitations of using small-brained rodents to model diseases that affect large-brain humans are becoming increasingly obvious as novel therapies emerge.
> — https://link.springer.com/protocol/10.1007/978-1-4939-7825-0_12

Comment: *Brained* is possible, although words such as brained, footed, eyed, etc are commoner in compounds like large-brained, two-footed, than stand-alone, and *brained* also has a slang meaning, "hit on the head", but still it's probably the best answer there is. *Brainless* is fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Sentient**: (antonym - **Insentient / non-sentient**)

OED
sentient, adj. and n.

> 1.a. **That feels or is capable of feeling; having the power or function of sensation or of perception by the senses.**
>
> 1632   Guillim's Display of Heraldrie (ed. 2) iii. xxiv. 250
> *Forasmuch as God would that the faculties both intelligent and
> sentient should predominate in the head [etc.].*
>
> 1879   G. H. Lewes Probl. Life & Mind 3rd Ser. I. 8   *We can define it [the relation of Mind to Life] by analytically distinguishing certain functions as sentient from other functions as nutrient.*

The word "sentient" implies that there is a brain in which feelings, perceptions etc, are processed.

*The Politics of Species: Reshaping Our Relationships with Other Animals* edited by Raymond Corbey, Annette Lanjouw

> Sentience, a capacity to experience, is necessary and sufficient for rights. Why? By definition, sentient beings can experience suffering and well-being. Also, sentient beings lose all opportunity for pleasant experiences when they die. (Insentient things such as plants don’t lose anything when they die because they’re completely unaware whether alive or dead. They have moral relevance oniy insofar as they affect sentient beings.) Therefore, all sentient beings need legal protection against humans who would needlessly deprive them of their well-being or lives. The whole point of laws is to protect interests. All (and only) sentient beings have interests.

Comment: That's a stretch.
The last quote mixes up sentiment and consciousness in my eyes.

Comment: There seems to be quite a distance between sentiment and sentient.

Comment: Was a typo. Still, I think the quote is mixing up those.

Answer (score -2):

How about "self-aware"? To be aware of the own existence is a direct result of having a brain.

Comment: Is everything with a brain self-aware?

Comment: @KillingTime: this is difficult to determine, because we can't ask animals directly about what they feel. What we do know, though, is that without a brain (i.e. as in plants) self-awareness is not possible at all.